Strange Binding Curve DNA:Protein Interaction

So I did some DNA:Protein Interaction studies using Fluorescence Polarisation Assays. I have fluorescently labelled DNA and add my Protein of interest. Down below you see an exemplary plot of the fraction (or %) of bound DNA by the protein, against the total protein concentration. For my target compounds I get really nice Kd values and also nice sigmoidal curves (black curve). But I performed some control reactions where the protein should bind much weaker, yet the plotted curves dont look sigmoidal at all and look more like asymptotic and sometimes almost linear (red curve). What I find strange is that there is an offset from start and but then it reaches "full" binding at the end.
How can I interpret the control curve (red)? Is this non-specific binding? Is this simply non-cooperative binding? How would I determine the binding constant in such a case?
I am a bit rusty in my biochem basics so I would be happy for some help!

How long is the DNA? What is the control protein? The experimental curve is sigmoid because of the log-scale, not because there is cooperative binding.

My controls are different DNA strands (always the same length as my "target", so 22nt). The protein is always the same.
Why is the "control" curve not sigmoidal if its also plotted on the log-scale?

Are you sure the control binds at all? How big is the change in fluorescent signal for your control DNA vs the DNA that binds to your protein? If you take the curves at face value, you would have to say your control DNA binds more tightly, which does not make any sense. There could be a secondary (small) effect of the protein (or the other components in the solution) on the control DNA, blown out of proportion because the analysis software assumes 100% binding at high protein concentration.

thats my issue, the endpoints of both control DNA vs. my "target" DNA are very similar. The polarisation for both is equally strong in terms of measured values. If it would have been much lower for the control, this would make more sense...

Could you show the raw data? Why is the fraction bound not zero in the absence of protein?
